# Is fdisk divides address space for created partition?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

On my system, it has one mem node created already in /dev (/dev/pmem). then i use fdisk command for creating a partition
After creating partition I apply lsblk command and my result is

```
pmem1       259:4    0  15.8G  0 disk
└─pmem1p2   259:7    0  14.3G  0 part
```

After that, I write mmap code (Refer devmam library) just like

```
off_t address = 0x00;
int width = 10;
void *virtladdr, *phyaddr;
int a = 5;
int *lendata = &a;
int main(void)
{
     int mode = 0x0777;
    char *filename = "/dev/pmem0";
    int fdout;
     if ((fdout = open (filename, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, mode )) < 0)//edited here
       {
               printf ("can't create file");
        return 0;
       }
     mapped_size = page_size = getpagesize();
     offset_in_page = (uint64_t)address & (page_size - 1);
    if (offset_in_page + (width * 8) > page_size) {
            mapped_size *= 2;
    }
    printf("map size %ld\n", mapped_size);
    phyaddr = mmap(0, mapped_size, (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, fdout, address & ~(off_t)(page_size - 1));
```

```
1 = I write value 10 on 0x00 address for /dev/pmem1
2 = I write value 20 on 0x00 address for /dev/pmem1p2
```

Then after I Read mmap

```
off_t address = 0x00;
int width = 10;
int main(void)
{
    int retVal = -1;
    int fd;
    unsigned long mapped_size, page_size, offset_in_page;
void *virtladdr, *phyaddr;

    fd = open("/dev/pmem0", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
if(fd < 0)
    {
            printf("file not open \n");
    }

    mapped_size = page_size = getpagesize();
    offset_in_page = (uint64_t)address & (page_size - 1);

    if (offset_in_page + (width * 8) > page_size) {
            
            mapped_size *= 2;
    }


    /* Map one page */
    phyaddr = mmap(0, mapped_size, PROT_READ,MAP_PRIVATE , fd, address & ~(off_t)(page_size - 1));
```

```
1 = Read 0x00 address from /dev/pmem1 My output is 10
2 = Read 0x00 address from /dev/pmem1p2 My output is 20
```

So what happened here why 0th address value is different? Is fdisk create two partitions which address starts from 0x00? Or I am in the wrong way?

Comment: There is not enough information. What is the starting offset (in 512 byte sectors or whatever) of the partition pmem1p2 within the disk pmem1? What are the `mapped_size`, `address` and `page_size` values for the `mmap` calls for the whole disk pmem1 and the partition pmem1p2?

Comment: Ok I will edit my question

Comment: So you are just mapping one page at the start of each device? The pmem1p2 device will start at some offset after the start of pmem1. fdisk defaults to 1 MiB partition boundaries, so with the defaults pmem1p2 will start 1 MiB or 512 pages after the start of pmem1. You can check the actual offset with `fdisk -l /dev/pmem1`.

Comment: Yes, the same page for each device So Both pmem1 and pmem1p2 are different partitions?

Comment: Disk /dev/pmem1: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DC3C862B-2856-034E-BDAE-13AE4E75F6D7

Device       Start   End Sectors Size Type
/dev/pmem1p1  2048 12345   10298   5M Linux filesystem 
Now, what i do can you explain to me ?

Comment: pmem1 is not a partition. pmem1p2 is a partition contained within pmem1. Based on the information provided, pmem1p2 starts at an offset of 2048 logical sectors (2048 * 512 bytes) from the start of pmem1. Writing to "address" (offset) 0 of pmem1p2 also affects the value at "address" (offset) 1048576 of pmem1. Writing to "address" (offset) 0 of pmem1 does not affect any value in pmem1p2 because the location is before the start of pmem1p2. (But writing to certain locations at the start of pmem1 will corrupt its partition table.)

Comment: What are the address and offset? Are they both different? I don't understand in offset field "address & ~(off_t)(page_size - 1)" what is the cause of bit-wise operation here? If I put only address in this field what happens? as mention in this link (https://comp.os.linux.development.apps.narkive.com/GP0AQLk6/how-to-map-to-physical-address-by-using-mmap-in-linux)

Comment: `address` is the name of your variable. The last parameter of `mmap` is an offset. The offset needs to be a multiple of the system page size, which is probably the reason for the bitwise logic in your code.

Comment: What's the meaning of this line "virt_addr = (char*)map_base + offset_in_page;" ?
https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/miscutils/devmem.c 
Why i can't get value directly from "map_base'?

Comment: It is in case you need to map an offset that is not a multiple of the page size to a virtual address. (1) Determine the offset of the address from the start of its page. (2) Map the offset to the start of the page to a virtual address, taking into account the offset from the start of the page in the calculation of the size of the area to be mapped. (3) Add the offset from the start of the page to the virtual address.